# Loading UIView template for a UIScrollView item from a .xib file

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, storyboard, autolayout, uistoryboard

I'm creating an iOS app screen including a UIScrollView positioned with Auto Layout in my Storyboard. The views in the scrollview are generated using a separate .xib file as template. The main problem is that when I load the preview of the xib file,it gets displayed on a full iPhone screen where instead I would need it to be sized as the UIScrollview containing it. In this mode the Preview is almost useless for me (as the position of the subviews are mismatched even if I try to place relative constrains) and I was wondering if there is any way to resize it in order to match the size of the Scrollview in the storyboard.

[image]